# How do I find which file contains a function?

Tags: database

How do I find where a Drupal function is defined? For example, in which Drupal file is `db_query()` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it at [**includes/database/database.inc**](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/7), line 2342.

Your editor may be providing a similar feature like the one implemented in Zend studio: When you press control while you click on the function name, it will take you to the file containing the implementation of that function.

Comment: no, cause im using notepadd++. :D

Comment: You can try eclipse also..It also provide the same features..

Comment: @Belmark If you continue to use NPP, you can also search for function definition in drupal root folders. But as suggested by mohit, it s good to use an IDE, saves you time.

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal.org API](http://api.drupal.org) shows which file contains a Drupal function, class, or method for which you are looking the documentation. In the case of [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7), this is what the site shows.

[image: screenshot]

That is also a link that takes you to a page showing the content of that file.

Notice that the documentation for Drupal 8 is not actually complete. For some reason, Drupal 8 files are not completely parsed, and it can happen you don't find on Drupal.org API a class or method Drupal 8 defines.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reasonably comfortable with a [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface).

Find functi`on`:
`grep -rn "on db_query" *`

Find cla`ss`:
`grep -rn "ss Node" *`